# Unit Testing: Testing a class which has an outside method

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-testing

```
class A {
    int a;

    public int add() {
        B b = new B();
        a = b.calculate(4, 5);
        return a;
    }
}

class B {
    public int calculate(int x, int y) {
        return x * y;
    }
}
```

I want to test class A, where and did not want to test the b.calculate() in the add() method.
So I need to mock the class B.

Here is my code.

```
@Mock
B bclass;

A aclass;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    bclass = new B();
    aclass = new A();
}

@Test
public void testAClass() {
    when(bclass.calculate(4, 5)).thenReturn(45);
    assertEquals(45, aclass.add());
}
```

The test getting failed. What's wrong with it?

Comment: please indent your code proberbly

Comment: *The test getting failed*: Have you tried to debug?

Comment: you instanciate B, so it is not a mock

Comment: I have tried it without creating instance also. Still fails.

Comment: Which Mocking Framework do you use?

Comment: In debug
It is showing.
Expected 45
Actual []

Comment: Using mockito framework

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Mockit framework.
You could try doing the following:

```
new MockUp<B>() {

            @Mock
            int calculate(int x, int y) // no access modifier required
            {
               return 45; // your value
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@Mock` annotation already generates the instance of the B. We do not need to create instance again here. Also, make sure you are annotating with Valid Runner or using the Rule.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

Let us know the error shown if it is not working. You can also refer the below link on using mockito.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html#mockito_usage

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the *hidden dependency* of class `A` to class `B`.

The answer of @Jens showed you how to solve this with <strike>PowerMock</strike> but I concider this as a surrender to your bad design.

The better was is to make this dependency *explicit* by injecting an instance of class `B` into objects of class `A` preferably as Constructor parameters.
<sub>Preferably using a *dependency injection framework* like `guice` or `spring`.</sub>
the you can use regulat Mockito constructs.

```
class A {
    int a;
    private final B b;
    public A(B b){
      this.b=b;
    }
    public int add() {
        a = b.calculate(4, 5);
        return a;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Mock
B bclass;

A aclass;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    aclass = new A(bclass);
}

@Test
public void testAClass() {
    when(bclass.calculate(4, 5)).thenReturn(45);
    assertEquals(45, aclass.add());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible with Mockito. With PowerMockito it works:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
public class BTest {

    A aclass;

    B bMock;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        bMock = PowerMockito.mock(B.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(bMock);
        aclass = new A();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAClass() {
        Mockito.when(bMock.calculate(4, 5)).thenReturn(45);
        Assert.assertEquals(45, aclass.add());
    }
}
```